# What is the grammatical difference between "think" and "support"

Tags: transitivity, objects

A friend of mine is learning English. Today, while studying, we ran into a situation that I (as a native English speaker) don't know how to explain.

*To think* and *to support* are both transitive verbs. So, why do they seem to take very different objects? What's the exact grammatical term for this difference?

Wrong usages highlighted by `*`.

> - *I think her.
> - I support her.
> - I think about it.
> - *I support about it.
> - *I think running for president.
> - I support running for president.

Does *think* actually take a direct object? Or is there something else going on?

Comment: In the sentence, *I think her*, "think" is *intransitive*, you need preposition "about"  to indicate the object of thought. Same like *I think running for president*, it's intransitive. *I support about it* is wrong because *it* is the object of the preposition(about), *not* the verb( support).

Comment: Oh! I see! *think* can be used intransitively, or transitively, and whether it is transitive or intransitive depends on what meaning of *think* I am trying to use. So, *I think sweet thoughts* is using *think* transitively. Right?

Comment: yes, that's right!

Answer (score 1):

in the infinitive: "to think about" is a different verb than "to think"

what you're looking for is *compound verb*

Answer (score 0):

You

> support *something*
>   I support Arsenal.

but

> think about *something*
>   I think about next summer when it snows.

the difference is popularized by the saying

> [Don't just think about it, do it!](http://digital.scaa.sk.ca/gallery/participaction/english/motivate/doit.html)

Comment: That's useful - but I am trying to find out what the grammatical name of this difference is - so that I can look up all the words that behave like _support_ vs. all the words that behave like _think_.

Comment: That isn't a saying... The Nike tag line is "Just do it!" If anything, the problem is you're mixing up your repetitive phrasing... "Don't think it, do it!" By using "it" in one place and "something" in the other, the entire thing falls flat.

Comment: It wasn't a reference to Nike. I've correct my saying, I was confused with "[Don't just stand there, do something!](http://www.quotes.net/movies/10160)" by Milly in Seven Brides for Seven Brothers.

Answer (score 0):

> To think and to support are both transitive verbs

*Think* isn't transitive.  You can be fooled because what follows is a clause describing what was thought, and many times the connecting *that* is omitted.

> I thought it wasn't there = I thought that it wasn't there (*it* is not an object of *thought*)

Prepositions go in front of indirect objects only when an direct object is also present and you specify that direct object first, and usually this preposition is *to* or *for*, rarely if ever *about*.

> I gave the ball to her = I gave her the ball

For that same reason *support about X* doesn't work if X is the direct object.